# Nuxt.js v2.7.1 Builds Successfully, Renders Blank Pages

Tags: nuxt.js

Using Nuxt.js v2.7.1, I can build successfully via `npm run generate` or `npm run build` but when I try to host the build locally using http-serveror via Firebase Hosting, my web app and all pages/routes render totally blank with no errors displaying in console. How can I can render the pages? What could possibly be the issue?

Note: using `npm run dev` I can access my web app just fine locally; my `router.base` is default `/`, I am not using any `.env` variables, and finally I am using Vuetify framework.

Firebase Hosted URL: https://gpstelv5.firebaseapp.com, note how all the scripts and css is being loaded just fine with zero errors, but somehow the app is not initializing.

Comment: I bet you have invalid markup in your layout or infinite loop somewhere in rendering logic. Your app hangs my browser if I trying to access 404 page. Get rid of most of your markup and check if it works.

Comment: Thank you @DreaMinder, yes you are correct there was an infinite authentication loop! something to do with my middleware, when I set auth state to true it was resolved.